# Setting font size in Kendo for Angular Dropdownlist

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoygtz-ph9dcs) I have a Kendo for Angular DDL with font-size set to 6px, but it doesn't work. The objective is to change the popup list font size. How to fix this?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
 <kendo-dropdownlist 
      [data]="listItems" 
      [ngStyle]="{ 'font-size': '6px' }">
 </kendo-dropdownlist>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public listItems: Array<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoygtz-g4dzoa?file=styles.css), added this line:

```
.k-animation-container li, .k-animation-container-shown li {
     font-size: 6px!important;
}
```

To your styles.css

Comment: Adding my-class to the DDL and to your CSS works only for this specific DLL

Comment: Nice and perfect, sorry for not getting the specific component.  =)

Comment: Actually, it didn't work for my-class, by mistake I only applied my-class to  'k-animation-container li', `.my-class .k-animation-container li, .my-class .k-animation-container-shown li` doesn't change the font size.

Comment: Blitz updated... Please check, you need to use the [popupSettings] property and set the 'popupClass'.

Comment: Great, perfect !!

Answer (score 2):

There is another (more flexible) solution:

1. add

   ```
   .popup-class {font-size: 6px;}
   ```

   to your styles.css
2. add

   ```
   [popupSettings]="{ popupClass: 'popup-class' }"
   ```

   to the template inside of kendo-dropdownlist.

With this solution you can style every dropdown list individually. Another solution could be to use item templates.